# How can i use ItemTouchHelper On Moving RIGHT or LEFT to move to a new Activity or Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, itemtouchhelper

I have implemented itemTouchHelper to my RecyclerView.Can I use the Drag direction of itemTouchHelper to navigate to another class or fragment for ex, if I use ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT to move to another Activity.

```
    ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.UP|
        ItemTouchHelper.DOWN|ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT,0) {
    @Override
    public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

    }
};
```

Comment: GestureDetector would be better for this feature. You can find examples of it on google.

Comment: Should i use it on onfling method ?

Comment: For your feature implementation, onFling() method you can use. You have to measure distance of X value (i.e startX and endX) and then you can implement your own logic.

Comment: Cool will give a try thanks!